# On USB Mount in Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Currently, I'm using LibUSBDotNet to detect when a USB is inserted. However, it takes a couple of seconds to mount, so currently, I'm running this code:

```
private void OnDeviceNotifyEvent(object sender, DeviceNotifyEventArgs e)
{
    //Log.WriteDiagnostic(e.ToString());
    Thread thread = new Thread(USBThreadStart);
    thread.Start();
}

private void USBThreadStart()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        if (drive.Name.Contains("/SomeUsbName"))
            Log.WriteDiagnostic("Usb Found.");            
}
```

In this, I start a thread that waits 5 seconds (more than enough to mount the device), then loops through all Drives for one with a given name (we have proprietary naming on our USB sticks for customers). The reason I do this is because DriveInfo.GetDrives() returns all USB sticks as Fixed types, instead of Removable types.

This works, but it certainly doesn't feel like the best way to go about it. Is there a better way, using Mono C# on Linux, to detect when a USB stick is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a library that does it (and I'm guessing you tried google). I can offer that you implement such library. You should take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116536/usb-connect-disconnect-notification). You can use this concept to implement the library. For example write a service from which you receive a notification through a pipe for example.